# How do you find one-sided limits *algebraically*?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, limits, continuity

Find $$\lim_{x\to\  -0.5^-}\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}}$$ 
Sorry, I have no idea where to start. I know how to find regular limits algebraically, but not one-sided.

Thanks

Comment: In this case you can just substitute $-0.5$ for $x$.

Comment: Ok but what about when $x$ approaches a function and there is more than one limit? How do you find which limit is true in a that case?

Comment: @AniketBinwade in practice, this will only happen when your function has a piecewise definition.  You find the limit by substituting into the definition associated with that side.

Comment: @AniketBinwade note that any algebraic function is continuous wherever it is defined (with a possible exception of the $0^0$ technicality).  So, if you *can* substitute and get an answer, that answer will generally be the overall limit, or the one sided limit if we're on the edge of the domain.

Comment: Substitute $x=-5-1/n$ And change the limit to $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it happens in functions with a single definition, i.e. $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{x}\neq \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0-}\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @Tony I would say that for that function, you can't "substitute and get and answer" since division by zero is undefined.

Comment: "Algebraically" is most unclear but might refer to computations such as $$\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}}-\sqrt3=\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{3x+3}}{\sqrt{x+1}\cdot{}{}{}\sqrt3}$$ which is $$\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{3x+3}}{\sqrt{x+1}\cdot\sqrt3}\frac{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{3x+3}}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{3x+3}}$$ which is $$-\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{x+1}\cdot\sqrt3\cdot(\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{3x+3})},$$ and when $x\to-\frac12$, the numerator goes to zero while the denominator goes to $$\sqrt{-\tfrac12+1}\cdot\sqrt3\cdot(\sqrt{-\tfrac12+2}+\sqrt{-3\tfrac12+3})=1{}{}{}\ne0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function 
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}}$$ 
is continuous at the point in question, so you have that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-0.5^-}\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow -0.5^+}\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{-.5+2}{-.5+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{1.5}{.5}}\\
=\sqrt{3}
$$
Since for a function continuous at a point $a$ you have
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)
$$

Answer (score 1):

There exist functions which have a 'left hand' limit different from the 'right hand' limit. Or perhaps the limit exists on one side at a particular number but fails to exist on the other. Consider the function

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\dfrac{2x-1}{\vert 2x-1\vert}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to0.5^-}f(x)=-1
\end{equation}

yet

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to0.5^+}f(x)=+1
\end{equation}

So

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to0.5}f(x)\text{ does not exist.}
\end{equation}

Notice that $f(x)$ is undefined at $\tfrac{1}{2}$ so one cannot substitute into the function to find the limit.

Comment: There's a typo in "exists" (and it should be "exist").

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the limit itself exists, than the left- and right-sided limits coincide. The easiest approach is then to simply compute

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

1. $$\lim_{x \to -0.5} f(x) = \lim_{x \to -0.5^{-1}} f(x)$$

if $f$ is continuous at $x=-0.5$

Is $$\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}}$$ continuous at $x=-0.5$?

What we need to check is if $$\lim_{x \to -0.5} \sqrt{x} = \lim_{x \to -0.5^{-1}} \sqrt{x}$$

and if $$\lim_{x \to 0-.5} \frac{x+2}{x+1} = \lim_{x \to -0.5^{-1}} \frac{x+2}{x+1}$$

It turns out both are true because

1. $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous at all points $x > 0$ and $\frac{x+2}{x+1}|_{x = -0.5} > 0$.
2. $\frac{x+2}{x+1}$ is continuous at all points $x \ne -1$

So this what we have:

$$\sqrt{\lim_{x \to 0.5}\frac{x+2}{x+1}} = \sqrt{\lim_{x \to 0.5^{-1}}\frac{x+2}{x+1}} \ \text{by continuity of} \ \frac{x+2}{x+1}$$

$$\sqrt{\lim_{x \to 0.5}\frac{x+2}{x+1}} = \lim_{x \to 0.5}\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}} \ \text{by continuity of} \ \sqrt{x}$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0.5^{-1}}\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}} = \lim_{x \to 0.5}\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}} \ \text{by continuity of} \ \sqrt{x}$$